# Prometheus request join values

Tags: request, prometheus, grafana

I am using the Prometheus API from my nodejs application (i am not using grafana)
I need to join 2 metrics in 1 request to get the 2 values.

**Let me explain with an example:**

I have a metric A and a metric B with the same label "server"

if i execute this :

```
metricA
```

//result of execution of "metric A"

> server  | value #A
>
> ---
>
> serverA | 10 
>   serverB | 20

```
metricB
```

//result of execution of "metric B"

> server  | value #B
>
> ---
>
> serverA | 30 
>   serverB | 40

I would like to do 1 request to obtain this result

```
a sort of "join (metricA and metric B) on server"
```

//with this final result

> server  | value #A  | value #B
>
> ---
>
> serverA | 10 | 30
>   serverB | 20 | 40

Thanks for your help

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

PromQL can't return two results for a given time series. The way to do this is to make two queries, and then join in your application.